# Why is 'JQ' used in JQuery and not $ - is this an old version of JQuery?

Tags: jquery, syntax

Beginner question alert....

We have an online system where we can insert page scripts to customise pages in terms of what page elements are shown etc.

An example script would be:

```
<script>
jq(document).ready(function() {
jq('[href="#page_2_form"]').closest('li').hide(); //# hide additional info tab
});
//# sourceURL=projectscreentidyup.js
</script>
```

The above script works but the following doesn't:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[href="#page_2_form"]').closest('li').hide(); //# hide additional info tab
});
//# sourceURL=projectscreentidyup.js
</script>
```

It is my understanding that the page uses JQuery (I could be wrong, but then what am I using(?)), and so I am trying to learn that, but I can't for the life of me work out why 'jq' needs writing at the start of each line item, and not '$' which all the tutorials are telling me to do.

Could it be that the online system is using an old version of JQuery?

Comment: Read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noConflict/

Comment: And yes, you can still use $ from argument `jq(function($){ /* DOM ready and $ alias in scope */ });`

Comment: `let jq = $; $=null;`  Convention is use `$` as it's quick easy and obvious. `jq` is relatively inconvenient to type.  At some point in your application's past, there may have been another use for `$` (hence noconflict as comment above) - or someone was confused by what `$` meant so changed it to `jq` to remind themselves it was jquery - or someone didn't like `$` and wanted to hate themselves by having to type `jq` all the time instead of a simple `$`